# I need to activate quotas on my centOS 7 machine

Tags: centos, disk-usage

I have a virtual machine installed with centOS 7. I want to activate quotas for a specific user using the / partition. How can I do that? Is it not recommended to do so?

I tried the /home partition but it's not mounted and I quickly understood that it's not a mounted filesystem in its own right so I can't activate quotas on it specifically.

Comment: You might want to RTM - See [Chapter 7. Implementing Disk Quotas](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-disk-quotas.html)

Answer (score 0):

Quotas are just a property of the filesystem, like most properties if you need to edit it you go ahead and do it in /etc/fstab. To support the user quota, simple add 'usrquota' to the appropriate file system, remount the file system/s and then add the user with 'edquota username'.